# Spinner popUpBackground cannot setting to transparent color in Android

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

Working on custom spinner for the first time. I have a spinner with background using nine patch image. Spinnermode is in dialog  mode.  Now I set custom layout for spinner and spinner item. Run the code but I did not the desired solution. There are corners seeing on the spinner item's background even I have set the background of spinner item . Searched alot but did not find the exact solution. I used code from this site [sourcecode form this site](http://adanware.blogspot.com/2012/03/android-custom-spinner-with-custom.html) their result is perfect but when I tried there whole code did not get the desired result seeing white background in the spinner items.

**main.xml**

```
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/dropdown_button"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingRight="13dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
       android:spinnerMode="dialog" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**spinner_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/spinneritem"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp" />
```

**spinner_item_list**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/blank_buttons"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/spinneritemlist"
        style="@style/SpinnerText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

</LinearLayout>

**in onCreate()**



ArrayList<CountryInfo> myCountries;
        myCountries = populateList();spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        CountryAdapter myAdapter = new CountryAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner_item, myCountries);
        spinner1.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

**function and adapter**

```
 public ArrayList<CountryInfo> populateList()
        {
            ArrayList<CountryInfo> myCountries = new ArrayList<CountryInfo>();
            myCountries.add(new CountryInfo("USA")); // Image stored in /drawable
            myCountries.add(new CountryInfo("Sweden"));
            myCountries.add(new CountryInfo("Canada"));
            return myCountries;
        }

    public class CountryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CountryInfo>
    {
        private Activity context;
        ArrayList<CountryInfo> data = null;

        public CountryAdapter(Activity context, int resource, ArrayList<CountryInfo> data)
        {
            super(context, resource, data);
            this.context = context;
            this.data = data;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {   // Ordinary view in Spinner, we use android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
            return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);   
        }

        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {   // This view starts when we click the spinner.
            View row = convertView;
            if(row == null)
            {
                LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_item_list, parent, false);
            }

            CountryInfo item = data.get(position);

            if(item != null)
            {   // Parse the data from each object and set it.

                TextView myCountry = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.spinneritemlist);

                if(myCountry != null)
                    myCountry.setText(item.getCountryName());

            }

            return row;
        }
    }
```

**My resulting images:**

[image: not perfect result of above code]

**printscreen of perfect result of sample code on their site(not from running their code)**
[image: printscreen of perfect result of sample code on their site(not from running their code)]

**screenshot of non perfect result of sample code(from running their code in my app)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/dropdown_button"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingRight="13dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog"
        android:popupBackground="@android:color/transparent" />//or desired color or drawable
```

**also try this in spinner_list_item**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/spinneritemlist"
        style="@style/SpinnerText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/blank_buttons"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I also did it before but it has no effect still the same thing.